# Why doesn't substitution in list context return a list of captures?

Tags: regex, perl, capture-group

As per [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), in list context, a matching operator `m//` with a regex that has a capture group and a `/g` modifier will return a list of captures:

```
my $str = "8a9b0c"; my @res = ($str =~ m/(\d)/g); print @res;

# Prints "8 9 0"
```

However, I can't find in either `perlop` or `prelre` any mention of why substitution operator will instead - even in list context - return the **number** of captures:

```
my $str = "8a9b0c"; my @res = ($str =~ s/(\d)//g); print "@res\n"

prints "3"
```

Why and where is that behavior documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `perlop`:

> Searches a string for a pattern, and if found, replaces that pattern with the replacement text and **returns the number of substitutions made.**

No distinction is made between list and scalar context. So it's returning the number of sustitutions, and then assigning that to the list. This simply converts the number to a list containing the number.

Answer (score 2):

From [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

> - `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualgcer`
>
>   Searches a string for a pattern, and if found, replaces that pattern with the replacement text and **returns the number of substitutions made**. Otherwise it returns false (specifically, the empty string).

The docs offers up no alternative spec for list context like the `m//` operator does.